# Saving a Video with OpenCV from webcam without showing video on monitor

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, imshow

I have a video reader and writer that is from [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/). I would like to be able to save the video without imshow() because when the camera is running there will not be a monitor attached to the computer. When I run the code with imshow commented out it does not save the video. The file that is "saves" to says "this file contains no playable streams. When I run the code with imshow() not commented out it works perfectly. Any suggestions on how to save a video input from a camera when there is not a monitor to use imshow with?

Comment: did you comment Waikey() as well? you need to comment that section as well